# Applying custom color on HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on highcharts , can anyone tell how to change color of points on the line graph ? by default it gives blue color for first , maron for second n so on. but i want to aaply custom colors. is there any function to change color manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change line color of graph by setting lineColor property. By default the line takes the color of the series from global configuration array of colors. Check this link for global array of colors. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors

For setting lineColor separately check this : 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.lineColor

Comment: Thanks @Tsimtsum , is there any function through which we can change points' color plotted on line ??? the link you referred show how to change the line color , but i'm looking to change color of points plotted on line .

Comment: Take look at the fillColor in markers http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.marker.fillColor

Comment: Thanks alot SebastianBochan :)